# Widget not displayed in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins, widget

I have a probem in my Wordpress widget. I have created a Wordpress template in HTML. I want to add this widget on my *About us* page, but the widget is not displayed.

This is my code in `function.php`

```
function wpb_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Custom Header Widget Area',
        'id'            => 'custom-header-widget',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="chw-widget">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="chw-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_widgets_init' );
```

And this code is my theme `page-about.php`:

```
<?php
    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'custom-header-widget' ) ) : ?>
        <div id="header-widget-area" class="chw-widget-area widget-area" role="complementary">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'custom-header-widget' ); ?>
        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

add bellow code in **function.php**

```
function wpb_widgets_init() {

register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => 'Custom Header Widget Area',
    'id'            => 'custom-header-widget',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="chw-widget">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="chw-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>',
   ) );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_widgets_init' );
```

and add this code in your **page-about.php**

```
<?php
 if ( is_active_sidebar( 'custom-header-widget' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="header-widget-area" class="chw-widget-area widget-area" role="complementary">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'custom-header-widget' ); ?>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: i have tried, but same. the widged is not showing. hmm.. what happend ?

Comment: @MuhammadAntok Antok in you code in lastline **`** symbol come

Comment: then maybe your php tags opening and closing mismatch